# Formulas not working in excel when i put 58+2 instead of 60?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to put `58+2` instead of `60` in Microsoft Excel cells. But, when I do that the cell is not counted for summation or other functions. How do I put `58+2` in a cell and get results?
If I put `=58+2` inside the cell, due to AUTOSUM it automatically turns to `60`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jfvD.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you want to calculate 60?  (And it shouldn't automatically turn to 60 [unless you press F9 while editing the cell], it should just **display** 60 while leaving the `=58+2` unchanged.)

Comment: This is being made for departmental exam results. The +2 is grace or additional marks given by the professor. So this is required to show separately.

Comment: Why don't you have a separate column for the separate information.  That will then allow you to show it separately, add it to totals where appropriate, provide reports on which professors have given additional marks and which haven't, etc, etc.  Forcing two pieces of numeric information into one text item is poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a couple of helper columns (which you can then hide from view). I'll give you two options/examples

[image: Examples]

In the example titled 'From helper columns to display' In Columns `C` & `D` I keep the raw values of the marks and the bonus. Then in Column `A` I use the 
formula

```
=C3&"+"&D3
```

To give my result. In column F I can then calculate totals etc. based on the columns `C` and `D`.

In the example titled 'From display to helper columnns' this assumes you already have the data stored as `xx+x`. In column C I use the formula

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A7, FIND("+",A7)-1))
```

And column `D`

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A7, LEN(A7)-FIND("+",A7)))
```

To get the actual values. I can then again use these columns to calculate my totals etc.

The columns `C` & `D` can be hidden for visual purposes. Both of these scenarios will achieve the same result it just depends what the format of your data is currently in as to which one you would use

Answer (score -1):

For any cell you want to calculate instead of hard-code, add an equals sign at the beginning

=58+2

will be evaluated by Excel to be a function rather than text and will evaluate it.